# The white-space property between blocks

Tags: html, css, xhtml, whitespace

Is the CSS 'white-space' propert supposed to be able to affect the whitespace between block elements?

For example, in the document used as an example in "[Whitespace in the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/whitespace_in_the_dom)" as follows, there is whitespace between the `</h1>` and the `<p>`:

```
<!-- My document -->
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <p>
    Paragraph
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

This whitespace is normally removed; for example, [the XHTML spec says that a conforming user agent must meet all of the following criteria](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-xhtml-modularization-20000105/conformance.html#s_conform_user_agent):

> In elements where the 'xml:space'
>   attribute is set to 'preserve', the
>   user agent must leave all whitespace
>   characters intact (with the exception
>   of leading and trailing whitespace
>   characters, which should be removed).
>   Otherwise, whitespace is handled
>   according to the following rules:
>
> - All whitespace surrounding block elements should be removed.
> - Leading and trailing whitespace inside a block element must be
>     removed.
> - Line feed characters within a block element must be converted into a space
>     (except when the 'xml:space' attribute
>     is set to 'preserve').
> - A sequence of white space characters must be reduced to a single space
>     character (except when the 'xml:space'
>     attribute is set to 'preserve').

My questions are as follows:

- If I use the [CSS white-space property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop) on the `<body>`, should this be able to preserve the whitespace between block elements (e.g. between the `</h1>` and the `<p>`)? Or is whitespace between blocks always removed, with the white-space property only affecting whitespace within blocks?
- The XHTML spec says that a `<body>` [cannot directly contain PCDATA](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xhtml-modularization-20010410/abstract_modules.html#s_structuremodule) (i.e. text). Does that mean that whitespace (being a kind of text) that's a direct child of the `<body>` tag is always insignificant/ignored, and cannot be enabled via CSS? If yes and whitespace between the `</h1>` and the `<p>` in the above example were ignored because it's a direct child of the `<body>`, would/should that whitespace still be ignored if there were a `<div style="white-space: pre">` immediately within the `<body>` and enclosing all the other elements?
- [The 'white-space' processing model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-model) starts with, "Any text that is directly contained inside a block element (not inside an inline element) should be treated as an anonymous inline element". What should I understand about pure whitespace (whitespace with no text)?
- Is there a rule (and if so, where is this rule defined) about removing whitespace within inline elements? For example in the following sequence `<p>The <strong> lazy </strong> dog.</p>` should the whitespace after the `<strong>` tag be removed? (The HTML 4 spec has [a rule about this for line breaks](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/appendix/notes.html#notes-line-breaks); I was wondering whether this rule also applied to other, non-line-beak whitespace, and whether this rule is mentioned/defined/allowed/assumed in any XHTML or CSS specification.)

Answer (score 1):

Your questions sure peeked my curiosity. I can hopefully shed some light on them.

The [XHTML schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1-schema/#xhtml1-strict) states the following three elements as `preserve`:

- `STYLE`
- `SCRIPT`
- `PRE`

This means that all other container elements should have suppressed the whitespaces around them. Your Mozilla link (["Whitespace in the DOM"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/whitespace_in_the_dom)) says:

> In Mozilla, all whitespace in the text
>   content of the original document is
>   represented in the DOM...

This becomes apparent when running a test page with plenty of whitespaces and breaks. Viewing the generated code (You can do this using the *Web Developer* toolbar: select **View Source** - **View Generated Source**) reveals that "the text content" means everything inside the `HTML` root tag. So, in other words, there's only whitespace suppression on the outermost tag (`HTML`).

Running the same page in IE8 tells a slightly different story (view the generated source by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> and in the Developer Tools, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> - <kbd>G</kbd>). They're not 100% conformant either, but way more conformant than Firefox. They're suppressing not only the `HTML` element, but pretty much everything else (as it should). They heed the `SCRIPT` and `STYLE` elements' `preserve` rule, but still leaves a break inbetween. In the body, it replaced multiple breaks with single breaks. Nested `DIV` tags (and their content text) on a single row was split up with breaks.

In short, both Firefox and IE8 are not *conforming user agents*.

And no, you can't suppress the whitespace between two tags with the `white-space` property (you probably could go about doing it with JavaScript/jQuery if you really wanted to). The `white-space` property specifies how to deal with whitespace in the content part of the element (e.g. `white-space: nowrap` prevents the text from wrapping).

Comment: I think that whitespace between two blocks is supposed to be suppressed automatically (but I'm not sure which spec specifies that). I was wondering whether the white-space property was meant to be able to preserve/render the whitespace that's between blocks (that's normally surpressed).

Comment: Yes, according to the schema, the whitespace in between two blocks should be suppressed, but it isn't due to Mozilla's decision to not follow the schema. If they had followed the schema, the `white-space` property would only preserve that whitespace if the two blocks had been wrapped by an element with `white-space` set to `pre` (e.g. the `PRE` element).

Comment: I'm getting the impression that maybe, according to modern specs (e.g. the XHTML v2 spec) no whitespace is ever removed by the parser from the DOM, and instead it's always in the DOM, and is either displayed or not according to the CSS white-space setting.